# ORA-61754: Using JSON type collections on Oracle Database release 23c or later requires a SODA driver for Oracle Database release 23c or later

Tags: oracle, driver, oracle-soda

I am trying to use soda oracle with python and my oracle database 23c. I haven't found any soda driver for this version. Does anyone has any ideas?

I cannot low my database version because everything else works fine with it